# Sum of uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be any set (could be uncountable). Let $f:X \to \Bbb R$ (real numbers) be any function. If the series $\sum f(x)$ is absolutely convergent for all $x \in X$, then the set $A=\{x\in X: f(x)\not=0\}$ is at most countable.

I am having 2 cases: a) if $X$ is countable. b) if $X$ is uncountable.

I am completely fine with a. But I am getting stock with b

What I did, I distinguish 2 cases;
first/ If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ (since $f$ is any function), then $A=\emptyset$ which is countable.

Second/if there is $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, then $|A|\le|X|$.
Now we have $X= A \cup \{x\}$ which makes $A$ uncountable (here I could not continue)

I would appreciate any help or hint.
Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what $\displaystyle \sum_{x \in X} |f(x)|$ would even mean if we had $|f(x)| > 0$ for an uncountable quantity of $x \in X$.  The way sums are defined, you need a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set to be summed.

Comment: @KajHansen There is a general notion of a sum $$\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$$ for arbitrary $X$ and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the family of finite subsets of $X$ ordered by inclusion. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a directed set and we define $$\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \lim_{F \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{x \in F} f(x).$$ See [limits of nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Limits_of_nets).

Comment: Thanks for that information @Adayah !  I was unaware of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No cases are necessary. Let

$$\sum_{x \in X} |f(x)| = L.$$

Then for each $n$ the set $A_n = \{ x \in X : |f(x)| \geqslant \frac{L}{n} \}$ is finite, because it has at most $n$ elements. Now just notice that

$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$

is countable as a countable union of finite sets.